# Wireless mouse, compatible to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mice

I need a mouse at work

- not more expensive than 50 €, better around 30 € or less
- wireless, preferable with dongle (and optional additional Bluetooth)
- suitable for palm grip*
- best would be 5 buttons + wheel or more (left/right, 2 thumb buttons, mousewheel with button)
- fully compatible with ubuntu, including dpi- and button configuration and, if applicable, Lighting
- at least up to 2000 dpi, preferable configurable

*For example, I like the size and weight of the SoundblasterX Siege M04 (135,6 mm length, 135 g). The Logitech M705 is too small. I don't know other models specifically.

Can you recommened a mouse for me?